# krakend api gateway panic: "X in new path conflicts with existing wildcard Y in existing prefix Z"

Tags: api-gateway, krakend

I have two webservices, and I'd like to manage both endpoints separated by the prefix using krakend API gateway.

Below is my configuration:

```json
{
  "version": 2,
  "name": "My API Gateway",
  "port": 8080,
  "host": [],
  "endpoints": [
    {
      "endpoint": "/api/entity/{entityID}",
      "output_encoding": "no-op",
      "method": "POST",
      "backend": [
        {
          "url_pattern": "/api/entity/{entityID}",
          "encoding": "no-op",
          "host": [
            "http://987.654.32.1"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "endpoint": "/api/entity/member/assign/{userID}",
      "output_encoding": "no-op",
      "method": "GET",
      "backend": [
        {
          "url_pattern": "/api/entity/member/assign/{userID}",
          "encoding": "no-op",
          "host": [
            "http://123.456.789.0"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

when I run it, error occurs:

```sh
panic: 'member' in new path '/api/entity/member/assign/:userID' conflicts with existing wildcard ':entityID' in existing prefix '/api/entity/:entityID'
```

As far as I understand, it seems the `{entityID}` on the first endpoint is conflicting with `/member/` in the second endpoint. Is this error expected behaviour or is there any problem with my configuration file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known limitation of the [Gin library](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin) that KrakenD uses internally, you can reproduce this behavior directly in the library with this go code, which will reproduce exactly the same issue:

```
package main

import "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"

func main() {
    r := gin.New()
    r.GET("/ping", handler)
    r.GET("/ping/foo", handler)
    r.GET("/ping/:a", handler)
    r.GET("/ping/:a/bar", handler)
}

func handler(c *gin.Context) {
    c.JSON(200, gin.H{
        "message": "pong",
    })
}
```

See the code in [this issue](https://github.com/devopsfaith/krakend-ce/issues/136#issuecomment-518282622).

The solution is to declare endpoint paths that are not colliding subsets of other endpoints. In your configuration the endpoint `/api/entity/member/assign/{userID}` is a subset of `/api/entity/{entityID}`.

Notice that `{placeholders}` are like using wildcards, so your first endpoint could be expressed in other systems like `/api/entity/*`, and therefore `/api/entity/member/assign/{userID}` is a positive match.

Any slight change in your configuration where the wildcard does not collide will fix this situation. As an example, the following two endpoints would work for you:

```
/api/entity/find/{entityID}
/api/entity/member/assign/{userID}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @alo on explaining this issue.

I have come across same one, as i have krakend endpoints in following manner:

```
GET: /v1/projects/{project_uuid}

GET: /v1/projects/{project_key}/portfolio
```

But surprisingly, by tricking krakenD like this worked fine.

```
GET: /v1/projects/{key}  // In swagger docs mentioned this key to be supplied as uuid

GET: /v1/projects/{key}/portfolio // In swagger docs mentioned this key to be supplied as string
```

For now this endpoints triggering my backend client as expected. hopefully this annoying thing gets fixed.